# Move left element under right element as screen size shrinks

Tags: html, css

Want to display an image on the left with text on the right.
As the screen width decreases, want to move the left image below the right text.

Tried this as a table. Can get the image above the text, but not below.
Tried a couple different things with DIVs, and none of them work properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/nrah8zc1/

HTML:

```
<h2>Method 1</h2>
<table class="table">
 <tr>
  <th><img src="http://placehold.it/240x320/f00/000.png&text=100x100" width="100" height="100" /></th>
  <td>blah blah blah</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th><img src="http://placehold.it/240x320/0f0/000.png&text=100x120" width="100" height="120" /></th>
  <td>another line of text</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<h2>Method 2</h2>
<div>
  <div class="right-or-top">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</div>
  <div class="left-or-bottom"><img src="http://placehold.it/240x320/f00/000.png&text=100x100" width="100" height="100" /></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="right-or-top">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</div>
  <div class="left-or-bottom"><img src="http://placehold.it/240x320/0f0/000.png&text=100x120" width="100" height="120" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table, .table td, .table th, div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    .table tbody > tr > th {
        border-top: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

.left-or-bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
}
.right-or-top {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .left-or-bottom {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .right-or-top {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Also want to state there are a lot of other things on this page on the sides... which makes absolute positioning difficult. Also looking to avoid a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to create two different elements for the text. The 1st one will be above the image and the other one from the right side of the image. And you are going to hide each element according to the screen size

example:

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {

.rightToTop1 {
    display:none;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rightToTop2 {
    display:block;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {

.rightToTop1 {
    display:block;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rightToTop2 {
    display:none;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="right-or-top1">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="left-or-bottom"><img src="sample.jpg"/></div>
<div class="right-or-top2">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</div>
```